# HTTP/2 with WebForms - What actually does this feature mean to a developer?

Tags: asp.net, iis, webforms, http2

I am exploring the current news for ASP.NET WinForms with .NET 4.6.

The resources I am currently looking at is this [Video overview by Microsoft Program Manager Pranav Rastogi](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IjMFLugGdqA) and an [article on DotNetCurry](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=1127). Besides the information, that I will require Windows 10 Preview, I can not decipher, what this really means to me as a WebForms developer.

To use HTTP/2 will I...

- need to make some changes in a config file?
- need to change something in the page / master page?
- use a different programming model when it comes to serve resources?

Of course, IIS will need to be configured, but this does not affect me as developer.

**Is there actually something I need / can do as developer to support HTTP/2?**

*Note: If someone sees this as a better fit on Programmers or other SE site, please move.*

Answer (score 0):

Basically, HTTP/2 is seemless for web services. The basic functions, request/response multiplexing and header compression, are defined at the network protocol level. That means it can be seen as the matter of web browsers and web servers.

But for the new features like HTTP/2 server push and stream priority/dependency, it needs to be considered for developers. To use those features, web browsers and web servers should provide APIs.